# Left Join on Same table - Not recognizing nested SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull two different values based on different criteria from the same table and in my Left Join of the same table it is not recognizing the SELECT statement.

The error is as follows:

```
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 7, char -1
SELECT.
```

The SQL Statement:

```
SELECT
b.dept,b.typ,c.brand,c.style,c.ext,c.description,
max(c.price),max(c.last_cost),sum(c.quan) "TOTAL INV",D.QUAN "WEB INV"
FROM
invt c
left outer join (
    SELECT dept,typ,brand,style,ext,description,sum(quan) as d.quan
    FROM invt WHERE store in ('997')
    group by dept,typ,brand,style,ext,description) d 
on (b.store = d.store and b.style = d.style and b.brand = d.brand)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
sku b
on c.style = b.style and c.brand = b.brand
where c.quan <> 0 or c.ord <> 0
GROUP BY
b.dept,b.typ,c.brand,c.style,c.ext,c.description
```

Comment: If you indent your code by four or more spaces (or one or more tabs), it'll be formatted correctly.  As it is, it's almost unreadable.

Comment: `d.store` does not seem to exist.

Comment: Store is in both tables, I just don't want the Store # to print on the report.  The Server seems to be stuck on not going past the Second Select statement.

Comment: `d.store` is not in your subselect. It doesn't matter if it's in the table or you don't want it in your report; it has to be in your subselect if you want to join against it.

Comment: we're on a 3rd party hosted SaaS system and they told me that they use interbase

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
SELECT dept,typ,brand,style,ext,description,sum(quan) as d.quan
```

to this:

```
SELECT store,dept,typ,brand,style,ext,description,sum(quan) as quan
```

You do not need the `d` alias here.

UPDATE:

As @Jeremy Holovacs mentioned, you also seem to be using d.store for your join but it does not exist in your subquery.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... I tried that, however it is still not getting past the Select statement after the first Left Outer Join.

Comment: I think your problem may be a combination of this and the problem that @JeremyHolovacs mentioned in his comment.